# MySQL query in other MySQL Query in WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, nested

I am building an affiliate system for WordPress. I am trying to get all customer IDs from the current user. I achieved it in PHPMyAdmin, but if i put it into a WordPress php-file, it doesn't work.

Here is the working code in PHPMyAdmin:

```
select  user_id,    
        meta_key,
        meta_value 
from    (select * 
        from prefix_usermeta
        where meta_key = 'sponsor_id'
        order by meta_value, user_id) meta_sorted,
        (select @pv := '1') initialisation
where   find_in_set(meta_value, @pv) > 0
and     @pv := concat(@pv, ',', user_id)
```

The query above puts out:

```
user_id     meta_key        meta_value
--------------------------------------
4           sponsor_id      1
9           sponsor_id      1
5           sponsor_id      4
6           sponsor_id      5
7           sponsor_id      6
8           sponsor_id      7
```

So this is working just fine! Now I need to put it into WordPress. I tried it this way and I think it should work like this:

```
$downlinequery = $wpdb->get_results("
    select      user_id, meta_key, meta_value 
    from        (select * from " . $wpdb->prefix . "usermeta
    where       meta_key = 'sponsor_id'
                order by meta_value, user_id) meta_sorted,
                (select @pv := '1') initialisation
    where       find_in_set(meta_value, @pv) > 0
    and         @pv := concat(@pv, ',', user_id)");
```

This was my first try. It didn't work. The second thing I tried (it is the same, just a bit cleaner:

```
$indownlinesquery = $wpdb->get_results('
    select      * 
    from        ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'usermeta 
    where       meta_key = "sponsor_id" 
    order by    meta_value, user_id');

$downlinequery = $wpdb->get_results("
    select      user_id, meta_key, meta_value 
    from        (" . $indownlinesquery . ") meta_sorted,
                (select @pv := '1') initialisation
    where       find_in_set(meta_value, @pv) > 0
    and         @pv := concat(@pv, ',', user_id)");
```

I am getting an empty array.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!